# Can I set grouped tableView section number in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

I dragged a tableView to my controller in storyboard. I set the type to grouped, but I don't know if I can set the tableView's section number in storyboard.

[image]

I can not see the tableview's content to Static Cells. If I do this it will report error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that in tableView because it does not support static cells.
However if you use **TableViewController** 
you can create static cells and you can create your desired sections and as well as add section number too.
Table View controller gives a more flexibility than Table View alone.

[image]